# How to replace NAs based on preceding and following numbers are zero

Tags: r, matrix, na

I have a large matrix full of NAs. For each row I would like to replace the NAs with zeros but only if the preceding and following values are zero. The number of NAs between zeros can vary so in the small example below NAs rows a.1 and a.1.2 will be replaced but other rows will remain NA

```
a.1<-c(1,1,1,0,NA,NA,0,1)
a.1.2 <- c(1,1,0,NA,NA,NA,0,0)
a.2<-c(1,0,1,1,NA,NA,0,1)
a.3<-c(1,0,0,0,NA,NA,1,0)
a.4<-c(1,0,0,1,NA,NA,1,0)

a_matrix<-as.matrix(rbind(a.1,a.1.2,a.2,a.3,a.4))
```

Comment: Can you add expected output matrix as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do it with a custom function:

```
my_func <- function(x) {
  r <- rle(is.na(x))
  vals <- r$values
  lengths <- r$lengths
  
  for (i in 2:(length(vals) - 1)) {
    if (vals[i] & !vals[i-1] & !vals[i+1] & x[sum(lengths[1:(i-1)])] == 0 & x[sum(lengths[1:i]) + 1] == 0) {
      x[(sum(lengths[1:(i-1)])+1):(sum(lengths[1:i]))] <- 0
    }
  }
  return(x)
}

t(apply(a_matrix, 1, my_func))
```

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
a.1      1    1    1    0    0    0    0    1
a.1.2    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
a.2      1    0    1    1   NA   NA    0    1
a.3      1    0    0    0   NA   NA    1    0
a.4      1    0    0    1   NA   NA    1    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick addition to the answer  by TarJae if this is useful to future readers as I hit a few issues that were not visible in the toy example.  The previous function failed if there are no NAs or if the NAs come at the start or end of the rows with no other NAs. I just added an additional if statement

```
if(length(vals)>= 3){
```

Examples where previous function had trouble (a.5:a.7):

```
a.1<-c(1,1,1,0,NA,NA,0,1)
a.2<-c(1,0,1,1,NA,NA,0,1)
a.3<-c(1,0,0,0,NA,NA,1,0)
a.4<-c(0,NA,0,0,NA,NA,0,0)
a.5<-c(NA,NA,0,0,1,1,0,0)
a.6<-c(0,0,0,0,1,1,NA,NA)
a.7<- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0)

a_matrix<-as.matrix(rbind(a.1,a.2,a.3,a.4,a.5,a.6,a.7))
```

New function:

```
my_func <- function(x) {
  r <- rle(is.na(x))
  vals <- r$values
  lengths <- r$lengths
 if(length(vals)>= 3){
  for (i in 2:(length(vals) - 1)) {
    if (vals[i] & !vals[i-1] & !vals[i+1] & x[sum(lengths[1:(i-1)])] == 0 & x[sum(lengths[1:i]) + 1] == 0) {
      x[(sum(lengths[1:(i-1)])+1):(sum(lengths[1:i]))] <- 0
    }
  }
}
  return(x)
}
```

Output:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
a.1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    1
a.2    1    0    1    1   NA   NA    0    1
a.3    1    0    0    0   NA   NA    1    0
a.4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
a.5   NA   NA    0    0    1    1    0    0
a.6    0    0    0    0    1    1   NA   NA
a.7    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
```